# ajax search suggest escape encoding

Tags: ajax, search, asp-classic, escaping

if encoding using escape(data) in javascript, how to decode it in server side?

I use ajax to post encoding data with escape javascript function, how can I decode it at the server side with classic asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing arguments in URL (get method), do not use encode()..  use encodeURI() function instead. Now, the data (I mean the parameters you pass) comes decoded automatically.

Comment: ar phone = document.getElementById("phone").value; var url = "/cgi-local/lookupCustomer.asp?phone=" + escape(phone); xmlhttp.open("get", url, true); xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); xmlhttp.send(null); if phone = "Ô", i will get "?" in lookupCustomer.asp

Comment: use like this, var url=encodeURI("/cgi-local/lookupCustomer.asp?phone=Ô"); xmlhttp.open("get", url, true); ......